# VB.NET wait until Query is done to to proceed to next code

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to run a query/job and need to wait until the job/query is done running to continue onto the next line of code in the VB.NET application.  How would I do this?

```
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'FWP1 Incremental Daily'"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()      

           (WAIT UNTIL FINISHES) - How do I Code this???

           \\Continue Code...........
```

Comment: As with my debugging experience, when you run a query, .NET waits for some response from the server regarding the query before it proceeds to the next code. What seems to be the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = True

con.Open()
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'FWP1 Incremental Daily'"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()    

Application.UseWaitCursor = False

MsgBox("Finished!")
```

Hope this will help.